# Why HttpServletRequest object get changed when it is forwarded from one servlet to another?

Tags: servlets, request

I am writing some simple code to forward an HTTP request from one servlet to another:

From Servlet1:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
    ...
    System.out.println("In Servlet1:");
    System.out.println("request: " + request.hashCode() + ", " + request.toString());
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/servlet/Servlet2").forward(request, response);       
}
```

From Servlet2:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
    ...
    System.out.println("In Servlet2:");
    System.out.println("request: " + request.hashCode() + ", " + request.toString());               
}
```

As far as I can understand, the "forward" method just request the web server to send the same HTTP Request to another servlet. So the 2 request objects in Servlet1 and Servlet2 should be the same. However, I got following result:

```
In Servelt1: 
request: 2106487657, org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7d8e7369
In Servlet2:
request: 887057147, org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@34df6afb
```

It seems the request object get changed? Why?

I am using servlet-api from Tomcat 7.0.50

Comment: Don't use `<code>`. Indent all lines with 4 blank spaces, or do it automatically by selecting the code and pressing the code button in the toolbar: {}.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I see the reason from the toString result. 
ApplicationHttpRequest is a wrapper, it wraps the original RequestFacade

Answer (score 0):

The toString result reveals the fact: ApplicationHttpRequest is a wrapper, it wraps the original RequestFacade

Comment: Dont forget the application server enter to the game and is is the responsible for wrap all the incoming request, it is the reason you see different objects, but inside have the same content, why some flags added by app server